# Give a subset that makes $f(x,y) = x - y$ a bijection.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I can't think of a subset that makes $f$ a bijection.

So far, I think the subset should have one constant number, like $(x, n)$ where $n$ is fixed, but this won't cover all positive integers?

$$f : \mathbb{N}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}.$$

Comment: Perhaps you have forgotten, but for a function to be unambiguously defined, you must include both the *domain* **and** *the codomain*.  Your question seems to imply that the domain is to be determined, but how about the codomain?  Is the codomain just going to be the image of the function under whatever domain we selected?

Comment: $f:\{0\}\times\{0\} \to \{0\}$ is an obvious example. Not sure about non-trivial examples at the moment.

Comment: In that case, here are some trivial examples:  Domain: $\emptyset$ and codomain $\emptyset$.  Another being Domain: $\{(0,0)\}$ and codomain $\{0\}$ or more generally domain $\{(a,b)\}$ and codomain $\{a-b\}$.  For more exotic and interesting examples, Domain $2\Bbb Z\times \{0,1\}$ and codomain $\Bbb Z$, or how about Domain: $\Bbb Z\times [0,1)$ and Codomain $\Bbb R$.

Comment: If you want very specifically the codomain to be $\Bbb Z$ and the domain to be a subset of $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$, then consider $\{(a,b)~:~a=1~\text{or}~b=1\}=(\Bbb N\times \{1\})\cup(\{1\}\times \Bbb N)$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that the function f(x,y) = x - y is not a bijection.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2789550/prove-that-the-function-fx-y-x-y-is-not-a-bijection)